# What is this light purple flowering ground cover?

Tags: identification

The small flowers look pretty, although the green foliage's somewhat wild - could this be a weed?

[image]

Comment: Wild geranium, these plants are sold at nurseries for the same price zonal geraniums are sold.  Stinky.  I think they are a bit stinky.  Lots of 'indigenous' flora is considered weeds, cause they are well adapted to the area.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is hardly any smell. With my eyes closed, it smells just like a growing plant, definitely not stinky. I'm thinking it's not geranium but something else perhaps?

Comment: Sure looks like wild geranium to me...did you squeeze a leaf, stem, run your hands through it?  My horses eat this and I smell it on their breath and poo.  Trust me, they managed to nab some on a ride wouldn't feed it to them on purpose, grins.  If it doesn't smell I think we should keep looking?

Comment: When un-touched, there's hardly any smell at all.. I squeezed, rubbed and tore some leaves and stem - not much smell still.. Yet everyone seems to think it's geranium - maybe here in my London garden a new non-smelling variety developed? :) .. Let's keep looking, thank you and good luck with your horses they must like the taste

Comment: Ugh.  My horses skin smelled like wild geranium.  There are lots of people that differ in olfactory standards, grins!  You might be immune or inured to this smell.  I think it is wild geranium.  Bamboo lives in London. I think I'll go ping her!

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like Herb Robert, a wild geranium with a particularly sharp smell. Personally I don't like the smell and I pull it out on sight.  It's very easy to pull out.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is hardly any smell. With my eyes closed, it smells just like a growing plant, definitely not a sharp smell. I'm thinking it's not geranium but something else perhaps?.. Very easy to pull out indeed.

Comment: @15UK The seed pods certainly look like a geranium, aka cranesbill, to me.  And the stem looks hairy and sticky as well, another common feature.  I've been looking at photos via Google and the leaves are slightly different than in your photo.  I wonder if that, and the scent, could be local variations.

Comment: Thanks. I've googled it too, found some similar looking plants but not exactly. Quite a number of people seem to think it's geranium - maybe here in my London garden a new non-smelling variety developed? :)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Herb-robert (Geranium robertianum) to me. If I'm right, it's a North American wildflower. Which doesn't mean that it won't act like a weed in your garden. Most geraniums are groundcovers and spread pretty well once they're established, so this one could take over a garden bed.

Comment: Also a wildflower in Europe and Asia.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The plant does indeed spread pretty well in my garden (London, UK)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Wild Geranium] [image: wild geranium leaf example] Geranium maculatum

And there are zillions of different 'flavors', slightly different leaves, different colors of flowers from bright white, to vivid blue, pale purples, pinks.  I'd leave them if you were me.  The bees LOVE these plants. Depends on your landscape goals, not mine.  I have a hard time finding plants to grow here much less with profuse flowers.  All plants flower some are just more profuse and visible than others.  I wonder what the honey tastes like if bees were visiting wild geranium?  That is how strong this plant smells.  But you have to crush or disturb this plant to get a hit!

I think if you pulled off some flowers and pulled off some dead flowers which will make them bloom even better at the same time reducing how much seed the plants set...you HAVE to be able smell sharp/musky/not my favorite smell at all.

I had a Johnson' Blue Geranium which is a hybrid of this wild one.  Flowers PROFUSELY from spring through fall.  I got kinda OCD and daily went out to snip old flower capsules, to keep it profusely flowering and boy did it!  The bees were in heaven.